# What R code can I use to separate the column into two?

Tags: r, text, dplyr, rstudio, tidyr

have tried many time using dplyr and tidyr. it is getting separated but all content is getting stacked in one column while other column is all NA's

> ```
> Card_ID.Campaign_Responce
> 100751677 F
> 103865437 F
> 104811325 F
> 101232348 F...continued (5959 data points)
> ```

Comment: Please refer to the help pages of this website on how to properly ask a question.

Comment: this data frame has 5000+ data points. after running the following codes I am able to separate the columns but data points get stacked in one column and other one goes all NAs

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `separate` function from `tidyr` package.

```r
df <- data.frame(Card_ID.Campaign_Responce = c("100751677 F", "103865437 F", "104811325 F",
                                               "101232348 F", "103332398 F", "105464138 F", 
                                               "100054168 F", "100116075 F", "103039321 F", 
                                               "101186950 T", "100284919 T", "105043270 F", 
                                               "103627192 F", "100624075 F", "100141427 T", 
                                               "105294724 F", "100591001 F", "100764619 T", 
                                               "106418294 T", "101497198 T"))

head(df)
```

```
> head(df)
  Card_ID.Campaign_Responce
1               100751677 F
2               103865437 F
3               104811325 F
4               101232348 F
5               103332398 F
6               105464138 F
```

```r
df <- tidyr::separate(df, 1, c("Card_ID", "Campaign_Response"), " ")

head(df)
```

```
> head(df)
    Card_ID Campaign_Response
1 100751677                 F
2 103865437                 F
3 104811325                 F
4 101232348                 F
5 103332398                 F
6 105464138                 F
```

https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html

Answer (score 0):

Edited after understanding the question properly:
You can also use `str_split_fixed` from `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)
df1 <- data.frame(str_split_fixed(df$Card_ID.Campaign_Responce, " ", 2))
names(df1) <- c('Card_ID', 'Campaign_Response')
```

data:

```
df <- data.frame(Card_ID.Campaign_Responce = c("100751677 F", "103865437 F", "104811325 F", "101232348 F", "103332398 F", "105464138 F", "100054168 F", "100116075 F", "103039321 F", "101186950 T", "100284919 T", "105043270 F", "103627192 F", "100624075 F", "100141427 T", "105294724 F", "100591001 F", "100764619 T", "106418294 T", "101497198 T"))
```

[image]